# MySql If Record Exists Inside Select Query

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Creating a forum-type site and I have 3 tables, one for storing user information (users), one for the original post (threads), and one for an upvote system like SO has (votes).

The votes table has 3 columns, id, userid, and threadid. When a user upvotes a thread, a record is inserted into the votes table. When I query for the thread I want to know if the user has upvoted for it, essentially if a record exists in the votes table with the correct userid and threadid. I can do this in two queries, but I think there has to be a way to get everything in one.

My query currently:

```
"SELECT t.id, t.title, t.content u.id AS uid, u.username 
FROM threads t, users u 
WHERE t.id = '".$userid."' 
AND t.author = '".$userid."'"
```

In case you need a better idea, the following will query the desired results ONLY if the user has upvoted. I need the query to still return if the record in the votes table doesn't exist (possibly return a vote value as null?).

```
"SELECT t.id, t.title, t.content u.id 
AS uid, u.username v.id 
FROM threads t, users u, votes v 
WHERE t.id = '".$threadid."' 
AND t.author = '".$userid."' 
AND v.threadid = t.id 
AND v.userid = '".$userid."'"
```

Also I taught myself (and am still learning) mysql and database design so if there's a better method/approach such as joining tables, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query is doing inner joins, which would only return records that appear on both sides of the join. You'd want to do a left/right outer join on the votes table instead, so that you'd still get user+thread records even if there's no matching vote record.

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, t.content, u.id, u.username, v.id
FROM threads AS t
INNER JOIN users AS u ON t.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN votes AS v ON (v.userid = u.id and t.id = v.threadid)
WHERE (u.id = $userid) AND (t.id = $threadid)
```

just guessing at this, but should be enough to get you started.